# How to flatten and merge nested array from each of child array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So i have this data:

```
let data = [
  {
    "purchase_id": 1,
    "product": [
      {
        "name": "A",
        "id": 1,
        "transactions": [
          {
            "price": 5,
            "qty": 2
          },
          {
            "price": 10,
            "qty": 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "B",
        "id": 2,
        "transactions": [
          {
            "price": 3,
            "qty": 4
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "purchase_id": 2,
    "product": [
      {
        "name": "C",
        "id": 3,
        "transactions": [
          {
            "price": 5,
            "qty": 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "D",
        "id": 4,
        "transactions": [
          {
            "price": 3,
            "qty": 4
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And i want to flatten array from each `data.product.transactions` data:

```
"transactions": [
    {
       "price",
       "qty"
    }
 ]
```

Expected output is:

```
[
  {
    "purchase_id": 1,
    "name": "A",
    "id": 1,
    "price": 5,
    "qty": 2
  },
  {
    "purchase_id": 1,
    "name": "A",
    "id": 1,
    "price": 10,
    "qty": 2
  },
  {
    "purchase_id": 1,
    "name": "B",
    "id": 2,
    "price": 3,
    "qty": 4
  },
  {
    "purchase_id": 2,
    "name": "C",
    "id": 3,
    "price": 5,
    "qty": 2
  },
  {
    "purchase_id": 2,
    "name": "D",
    "id": 4,
    "price": 3,
    "qty": 4
  },
]
```

I have tried to use object assign, reduce but my code doesn't work. Thank you

Comment: Add the code that you have tried, it would be more helpful. Also there is no need to paste all of your data just an example will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create the objects, and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to flatten the sub-arrays at each level:

```js
const data = [{"purchase_id":1,"product":[{"name":"A","id":1,"transactions":[{"price":5,"qty":2},{"price":10,"qty":2}]},{"name":"B","id":2,"transactions":[{"price":3,"qty":4}]}]},{"purchase_id":2,"product":[{"name":"C","id":3,"transactions":[{"price":5,"qty":2}]},{"name":"D","id":4,"transactions":[{"price":3,"qty":4}]}]}];

const result = [].concat(...data.map(({ purchase_id, product }) => 
  [].concat(...product.map(({ name, id, transactions }) => 
    transactions.map((o) => ({
      purchase_id,
      name,
      id,
      ...o
    })
)))));

console.log(result);
```

If you want to avoid the temp sub-arrays, and the flattering, use nested [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) calls, and push the created objects to a predefined array:

```js
const data = [{"purchase_id":1,"product":[{"name":"A","id":1,"transactions":[{"price":5,"qty":2},{"price":10,"qty":2}]},{"name":"B","id":2,"transactions":[{"price":3,"qty":4}]}]},{"purchase_id":2,"product":[{"name":"C","id":3,"transactions":[{"price":5,"qty":2}]},{"name":"D","id":4,"transactions":[{"price":3,"qty":4}]}]}];

const result = [];

data.forEach(({ purchase_id, product }) => 
  product.forEach(({ name, id, transactions }) => 
    transactions.forEach((o) => result.push({
      purchase_id,
      name,
      id,
      ...o
    })
)));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [];
data.forEach(x => {
  x.product.forEach(y => {
    y.transactions.forEach(z => {
      z["name"] = y.name;
      z["id"] = y.id;
      z["purchase_id"] = x.purchase_id;
      arr.push(z);
    });
  })
});
console.log(arr);
```